# remember_token missing when add user in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

hello i want to add user when admin log in. i use  default Register form.

it success but remember_token is missing and parssword not decrypt.

this is my controller :

```
public function create()
{
    return view('admin/dosen.create');
}

public function store(CreateDosenRequest $request)
{
    User::create($request->all());
    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan!');              
}
```

and my request :

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'username'=>'required|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',

    ];
}
```

Route :

```
Route::resource('/admin/dosen', 'AdminController',
            ['except => show, index']);

});
```

Comment: Gonna have to provide a more detail of what is going on. What is missing the remember_token and passwords are not encrypted they are hashed.

Comment: @lagbox in my database remember_token row is empty and password not encrypted

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="#"><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"></form>
```

Just add this in html form.Working :)

Comment: it's working. can you tell me how to not redirect login after register?
because i want admin still login when push register button